# Error setting Python 3.3 as runtime from nettbeans 8.1 (window 10) Python Platform manager

Tags: python, netbeans, platform

I have Netbeans 8.1 on Windows 10 laptop
I have installed Python 3.3 on the same windows 10 laptop above
Launched the Python Platform Manager from Netbeans->Tools->Python Platforms
Clicked New Button to add the Python 3.3 as a new platform Runtime
Navigated to the Python3.3 install directory and selected Python.exe
I get a error Popup "Invalid Python Type"?

Question is: How do I add a Python3.3 to Netbeans 8.1 (Windows 10) as a new Python Platform run time.
Thanks